# Kill oldest process running using diagnostics C#

Tags: c#, .net, process

I am writing some code in my c# program to go through all of the windows in the IE process and close one based on the title:

```
Process[] myList = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
foreach (Process item in myList)
if (item.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Window Title"))
{
    item.Kill();
}
```

However, the problem is that the window that I want to close has the same name as other windows that I do not want to close. I have searched for methods and classes to use but do not see anything that could work. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the oldest process by using the following code

```
Process myOldestProcess = myList.OrderBy(it => it.StartTime).FirstOrDefault();
```